# Pandas read_html to retrieve Table

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to extract Olympic Games medal table from wiki URL, and for which I'm using Python Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-time_Olympic_Games_medal_table'
df = pd.read_html(url, skiprows=7, header = None)
df[0]
```

However, I lose 5 rows those are

> names
>
> Afghanistan (AFG)      Algeria (ALG)
>
> Argentina (ARG)
>
> Armenia (ARM)

Once I set skiprows = 0 - 6  will return disaster table frame, so at least I must set skiprows to 6.

Does any talent recommend any trick to retrieve the Perfect Table instead insert rows manually ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `skiprows` to `2` and then select second table by `df[1]`:

```
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-time_Olympic_Games_medal_table'
df = pd.read_html(url, skiprows=2, header = None)
a = df[1]
print (a)
                                              0   1     2     3     4   \
0                               Afghanistan (AFG)  14     0     0     2   
1                                   Algeria (ALG)  13     5     4     8   
2                                 Argentina (ARG)  24    21    25    28   
3                                   Armenia (ARM)   6     2     5     7   
4                         Australasia (ANZ) [ANZ]   2     3     4     5   
5                       Australia (AUS) [AUS] [Z]  26   147   163   187   
6                                   Austria (AUT)  27    18    33    36   
7                                Azerbaijan (AZE)   6     7    11    25
```